# Dismiss custom dialog from async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I couldn't even create a custom dialog on the async task itself, so I called a method to show it and this is my method:

```
public void showCustomLocationDialog(String title) {
    final Dialog customDialog = new Dialog(this);
    customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_location_dialog);
    customDialog.setTitle(title);

    if (!customDialog.isShowing()) {
        // set the custom dialog components - title, ProgressBar and button
        TextView text = (TextView) customDialog.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text.setText(title);
        customDialog.show();
    }else if (customDialog.isShowing())
    {
        customDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

The error I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
....
```

What I'm doing here is calling this method on `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute`.

I tried creating the dialog onPreExecute, however, I was met with an error. Particularly with "setContentView".

How can I dismiss my customdialog when asynctask is done?

Comment: when an `AsyncTask` is finished the `onPostExecute` function is called so you should put your `customDialog.dismiss();` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android not Allows to change the gui in thread that is not `android main thread`. in `activity.onCreate()` or `view.onClick()` atc.. android call from the `main thread`.

The Problem : you call `customDialog.dismiss();` that change the gui from other thread

in `AsyncTask` put your gui change Only in `onPostExecute`, this method call by main thread, be sure that you call `AsyncTask.execute()` from main thread, if not the `onPostExecute` will not call,

Answer (score 0):

Hello you try UI operation inside activity.runOnUiThread in AsyncTast

**onPostExecute{
       Activity.runOnUiThread{ Dialog.dismiss() }**

}